# create variable at each iteration MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
for(i=1:n)
x[i]=value    %create a new variable for each x: x1,x2,x3
end
```

any recommendations?

Thank you

Comment: MATLAB itself recommends not to create a variable at each iteration, so what should we say?

Answer (score 8):

You do not need different variables. You can do it with `eval` but I would not go into it and recommend it.

My answer depends on the dimensions of your `value` variable. I would say if it is a single number then use the following:

```
for i=1:n
   x(i)=value;    
end
```

If `value` is a string or matrix or different size vectors etc., then use cell array.

```
for i=1:n
   x{i}=value; %notice curly braces.    
end
```

Comment: the answer with `eval` is already here. I don't have to show it to you.

Comment: +1. @user3228903 And remember to [preallocate](http://obasic.net/preallocate-before-you-loop-it-in-matlab) if possible

Answer (score 3):

You should never do this. Just to be clear, don't use eval to do this this way:

```
eval(['x' num2str(count) ' = i^2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to make each `x[i]` a field in a structure `S`. Then you can do something like this

```
S = struct;
i = 1:n;
tmp = strsplit(num2str(i));

for i = i
    S.(['x',tmp{i}]) = value(i);
end
```

Then calling `S` yields

```
S = 

 x1: 0.6557
 x2: 0.0357
 x3: 0.8491
 x4: 0.9340
 ...
```

(In this case I just used random numbers for `value`.) You cannot make `x.1, x.2` and so on because fields that start with a numerical character like `'1'` are not allowed. If you were content with fields like `a, b, c ...` then you could generate `x.a, x.b, x.c ...` in a similar way to above.